# Wrap findOne in sails.js User controller to make findMe

Tags: sails.js

I'd like to create a new endpoint "/user/me" to call an action on my User controller called findMe(req, res). I'd like it to behave almost identically to the blueprint "/user/:id" which routes to findOne(req, res), except it will return the current user's data based on the logged in user's id (which is stored in req.session after login).

Is there an easy way to write findMe so it can pass the user ID to findOne and leave all the remaining request processing to the core sails findOne action?

I'm keen not to work with the findOne methods on User model directly but rather, use findOne on the User controller because it has added benefits, like honouring the ?polulate=... parameter, etc. That's said, tell me if this is a bad idea. I'm slightly concerned about the security implications - could s malicious user get to other users data via a forged /user/me request?

In other environments I've known this as server side redirects (different to client side redirects / 30x).

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally access the blueprints from a controller. This is how you would do it if you store the user id inside the session as `req.session.user.id`:

```
// UserController.js

module.exports = {

  me: function (req, res) {
    req.params.id = req.session.user.id;
    return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.findone(req, res);
  }

};
```

However, this would not allow you to use other params such as `populate`.

I personally think you should implement your own action as it won't be really complicated and will be easier to secure the requests.

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67265403/how-to-call-custom-controllers-on-api-reques-in-sails-js