# How to call custom controllers on API reques in sails.js?

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js

I have my directory structure like this:

```
-api
 -controllers
  -profile
   -create.js
```

inside create.js

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
... some code ....
}
```

I am calling the route like this

```
-config
 -routes.js
```

in routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
  // create new user
  'POST /api/v1/user/create': {action: 'profile/create'}

};
```

I want to invoke `createUser` function on this above request, but it is not working for me, the function is not being called, Please help.

Comment: @MattGarnett
Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export the controller function by assigning it to `module.exports` not to `module.exports.createUser`.

Could you try it as below?

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
... some code ....
}
```

Comment: Yes that and I guess we had to make the standalone files using sails generate action generate profile/create --no-actions2. But this works too

Comment: I had previously made the files manually, and using command. Thanks for help :)